# Preventing body tag to scroll when modal is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to prevent the body tag to be scrolled when my modal is open. I have tried the solutions here but none of them works for me. I tried to implement wheelscroll function, but its not preventing the scroll of the body div. The css solutions are not working either.

```
my HTML
            <div class="box">
                <a class="button" href="#popup1">CENIK</a>
            </div>
            <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
                <div class="popup">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" height="
                      35px;"></div>

                    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                    <div class="content">
                       Lorem ipsum............
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

my JS file

```
/* eslint-disable */

function popupOpenClose(popup) {

    /* Open popup */
    $(popup).show();

    /* Close popup if user clicks on background */
    $(popup).click(function(e) {
        if ( e.target == this ) {
            if ($(popup).is(':visible')) {
                $(popup).hide();
            }
        }
    });

    /* Close popup and remove errors if user clicks on cancel or close buttons */
    $(popup).find("button[name=close]").on("click", function() {
        if ($(".formElementError").is(':visible')) {
            $(".formElementError").remove();
        }
        $(popup).hide();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-js=open]").on("click", function() {
        popupOpenClose($(".popup"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to set your `body` to `overflow: hidden;` when the modal is open. It works fine but be warned that the scrollbar might make the width jump, depending on the OS/browser.

Comment: "It's not working" is not giving us a lot of information to work with to help you. I used this technique a few days ago. So I think we'll need a preview of your full page to assess what can be done.